# how to change size unit in flutter

Tags: flutter

I was developing an app that worked smoothly on the emulator and my phone but when I tried it on a third device there were yellow zones ( only a part of the screen was displayed).
I thought using sizedbox(height: 30), will work for any device cause I didn't specify the measurement unit.

is there any solution to this type of problem?

Comment: yellow zones = overflow widget, you can try to use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3` instead. it will give you 30% of screen height of any device you will used later on. you can change the `0.3` into the size you want to

Comment: depends, try using LayoutBuilder. More about [adaptive-responsive layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive)

Comment: thanks, I've solved it using MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `flutter_screenutil` package.
Most important thing you need to set the fit size (Find your UI design, look at the dimensions of the device screen and fill it )